# Is this that a conjunction or a pronoun?

Tags: vocabulary

> Harry did the best he could, trying to ignore the stabbing pains in
>   his forehead, which had been bothering him ever since his trip into
>   the forest. Neville thought Harry had a bad case of exam nerves
>   because Harry couldn't sleep, but the truth was that Harry kept being
>   woken by his old nightmare, except **that** it was now worse than ever
>   because there was a hooded figure dripping blood in it.  (Harry Potter
>   and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is that-clause the complement of except or does that refer to something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's helpful to describe this example as either a "that-clause" or a "complement".

In fact, the word ***that*** is an entirely optional [conjunction](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conjunction) in this case. The word ***except*** here (also a conjunction) indicates that whatever follows at least *partially* refutes or otherwise "qualifies" the preceding statement.

The meaning would be the same with ***though*** or ***but*** instead of *except [that]*. The only difference being that neither of those conjunctions can be followed by *that* in this context.

Specifically, the statement *Harry kept being woken by his old nightmares* is at least "misleading", because it implies that what's happening is the same as what *used to happen*. ***But*** it's not, it's ***worse***.

Note that the additional words *now* and *than ever*, and the entire clause from *because* on, are all irrelevant to the grammar involved in this usage of *except [that]*.

Comment: +1 *Except* has always wobbled between verb, preposition, and conjunction. I think *except that* represents historical preposition+complementizer; but that construction is no longer 'sensed' by its users, and *except that* is now just a compound conjunction.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, Can I accept your ‘except that’ as ‘but’, which is said in Webster’s “except (that): conjunction 3. only” (= only: conjunction 1.a. but, b. however)? [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/except) [link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/only)

Comment: @Listenever: You can certainly accept that in your particular context, *except [that], except insofar as, but* and *though, although* are all effectively equivalent (to something like *apart from the fact that...*). And in informal speech, *only* and *except **for*** are also reasonably common alternatives. They all just introduce a "limiting qualifier" that modifies the preceding statement by pointing out why it's not *completely* true.